# How does the distinct function work?

Tags: scala

The Scala website doesn't show me how the actual `distinct` function of [`List`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List) works and there is no full signature of the function.

Is there a way to find the actual function signature or its definition ?

Comment: What "full signature" do you think is missing? It takes no parameters and returns a List[A]... which is what the Scaladoc already says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `distinct` function of `List` is defined in [`SeqLike`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.SeqLike).

You can find its `distinct` implementation on [GitHub](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.7/src/library/scala/collection/SeqLike.scala#L497-L512).

```
// Scala 2.11.7
def distinct: Repr = {
  val b = newBuilder
  val seen = mutable.HashSet[A]()
  for (x <- this) {
    if (!seen(x)) {
      b += x
      seen += x
    }
  }
  b.result()
}
```

Note that at the top of every ScalaDoc page (below the description), there is a link to the source file on GitHub.